# Zapier trigger based on filter criteria in the past not new entries

Tags: gmail, zapier

Many zaps in Gmail or Sheets, are designed to trigger when a new entry or email matches filter criteria. But can a zap be triggered to act on entries or emails that already exist, simply by fitting that filter criteria? Is there some way to trigger a whole bunch of existing entries?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

This is a great question for our support team! They'll be able to explain it more specifically (and tailor it to your use case) but the short answer is "mostly yes". If you create a filter, turn the zap on, then dump a bunch of rows/emails/items into that filter, then Zapier will see them all as new and trigger appropriately. Exact possibilities depend on the app and what you want to filter by.

Again, I'd reach out to support (`contact@zapier.com`) since they're great at addressing stuff like this!

Comment: If anyone else cares to weight in, I'm not able to get this to work in gmail. thought I'm sure it does elsewhere. Even relabeling old Gmails won't trigger zaps. Only new entries. I wonder if Gmail hasn't blocked this function for some reason?